# Add "> text" quote markup to chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown, blockquote, chat-faq

It's possible to quote a block of text in chat by preceding it with a greater-than sign and a space:

```
> I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts
```

This produces a nice vertical dotted line in the message.

[image: chat message with a blockquote]

However, that's not specified in **[the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)**. I think it should be added.

Comment: Do you?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: I don't, but the person I'm quoting does.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's missing in _both_ chat FAQs.

Comment: The greater than sign *must* also have a space between it and the text. It's not necessary in posts but it will not work if you omit the space in chat.

Comment: @Catija, good observation. I'll mention that in the post.

Comment: It also *only* displays properly in conversations themselves. In search, the starred sidebar, and all other overviews, it doesn't display properly (it shows the message as is).