# Omitting the space after the ">" in chat, for a multiline quote, works half-way

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, blockquote

Quotes in chat are [supposed to require a space after the `>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308808/add-text-quote-markup-to-chat-faq#comment1006370_308808)

```
> note the space between ">" and "note"
```

Thus, as expected, `>quote` renders as ">quote", and `> quote` renders as "| quote" (pipe character to represent quote formatting). However, if you omit the space after the `>` in a *multiline* quote, it works halfway. Specifically, you get the quote formatting, but the `>` stays connected to the first word.

They say pictures are worth a thousand words, so here's a picture summarizing the above:

[image: image showing bug]

Markdown for each message, in order:

- `>quote`
- ```
  >quote
  doop
  ```
- ```
  > quote
  doop
  ```
- ```
  quote
  doop
  ```
- `> quote`

I think the intended behavior is for this to break *all* the way, not just half-way - so no quote formatting at all for this case. But I'd be fine with a fix to make it work all the way as well.

---

On the proposed duplicate:

It's a feature request for this to work. I'm pointing out a specific way in which it works halfway, and saying that's a bug; it should probably be broken all the way. Also, that question only includes single-line quotes, and this behavior appears only in multiline quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Be a little more flexible with adding quotes in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127135/be-a-little-more-flexible-with-adding-quotes-in-chat)

Comment: @Rob (as the edit also notes) that seems different. That's a feature request (which, really, is requesting multiple features).  This is about the current implementation working inconsistently, which is almost certainly a bug.

Comment: @Rob [Multiline quotes in chat work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192901/1017231). The way they were implemented required a space after the `>`, as all other quotes in chat. Or it should. So Shog's answer (a further feature-request) was [[tag:status-completed]], but the way it was completed has a bug.

Comment: @Rob No, I'm saying the other post is a feature request asking for new functionality (not requiring a space between the caret and the text, and allowing quotes to be directed at users), and this is reporting a bug with the _current_ functionality (the current behavior of multiline quotes isn't working as intended).  You could certainly link it as a related post in the comments, which would link the two, but there's no reason to mark it as a duplicate, because it's not the same thing.

Comment: @RyanM, I'm going to have to [agree with bobble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366774/omitting-the-space-after-the-in-chat-for-a-multiline-quote-works-half-way?noredirect=1#comment1222259_366774)'s last comment and stick with [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366774/omitting-the-space-after-the-in-chat-for-a-multiline-quote-works-half-way?noredirect=1#comment1222258_366774).

Comment: @Rob I also agree with bobble's comment, which clearly cuts in favor of this _not_ being a duplicate.  Bugs in a feature are not a duplicate of a different feature request in which someone requested the feature in an answer (and it appears the other reviewers [agree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/78603)).

Comment: bobble, you've got one in seven viewers (now) upvoting for this, if you can gain sufficient votes you should flag this for [tag:status-review]; though actual repair of chat bugs usually takes a lower priority over site bugs.

Comment: Ryan, [that's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366774/omitting-the-space-after-the-in-chat-for-a-multiline-quote-works-half-way?noredirect=1#comment1222262_366774) not how dupes on MSE are determined.